# How do I handle http requests larger than 1024 bytes in netty?

Tags: java, http, netty, reverse-proxy

I'm writing a simple reverse proxy using Netty. Since I don't want to deal with the raw bytes myself I've added a request decoder and object aggregator to the handler pipeline, as well as a response encoder and finally my own handler, something like this

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH));
p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
p.addLast(new FrontendHandler(...));
```

my `FrontendHandler` extends `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest>`, so it has a

```
// Start reading as soon as a request comes in...
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.read();
}
```

and a

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest request) {
    // copy request, fix headers, forward to backend server
}
```

What happens is that the server hangs wating if a request comes in that is larger than 1024 bytes (e.g. it has some cookies). With some trial and error I found that if I set the `ChannelOption.AUTO_READ` on the handler everything works fine, so it looks like my old code was missing a `ctx.read()` call somewhere, but I have no idea where. If I do something like

```
@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.read();
}
```

then I get exceptions inside the `channelRead0` that seem to be causes by dealing with a still incomplete http request, which kind of defeats the purpose of using a request decoder/object aggregator. What am I missing?

Comment: kindly check this it might help...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170564/in-netty-we-can-only-write-and-receive-data-less-than-1024bytes-how-we-can-wri/11373405#11373405

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the HttpObjectAggregator can handle chunked messages.  You can try using the HttpChunkAggregator, something like:

```
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder(4096, 4096, 100*1024*1024));
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(100*1024*1024));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("hndlr", new FrontendHandler(...));
```